# string compare in java

Tags: java

I have a ArrayList, with elements something like:

```
[string,has,was,hctam,gnirts,saw,match,sah]
```

I would like to delete the ones which are repeating itself, such as string and gnirts, and delete the other(gnirts). How do I go about achieving something as above?

**Edit**: I would like to rephrase the question:

Given an arrayList of strings, how does one go about deleting elements containing reversed strings?
Given the following input:

```
[string,has,was,hctam,gnirts,saw,match,sah]
```

How does one reach the following output:

```
[string,has,was,match]
```

Comment: attempt something first at least. Then we'll help

Comment: [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: This question might be better phrased with reference to anagrams.

Comment: +1 to Finbar, for really reading to question ("string" should be equal to "gnirts"). -1 to James W for not being more explicit about this.

Comment: Thilo, I agree I should have been clearer. I did mean "string" should be equal to "gnirts". Thanks for the -1 :)

Comment: Should "string" also be equal to "ingstr" ? Any re-ordering of letters or just the reverse string?

Comment: Just the reversed string Thilo.. nothing else.

Comment: the phrasing of your question and what you actually want are worlds apart.

Comment: People, I have rephrased the question now. Hope it reads fine.

Comment: How about if the output is `[gnirts, sah, saw, hctam]`?

Comment: Yea, thats acceptable too Ted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
for(String word: words) {
    if(result.contains(word) || result.contains(new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString())) {
        continue;
    }
    result.add(word);
}
// result
```

Comment: Finbarr: when I try to implement your code, I get a compile error: "')' expected
    if(result.contains(word) || result.contains(new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString()) {                                                                    ^1 error
Also, could you maybe explain what the pipe operator does here? (Sorry, Java newbie here).

Comment: Serious question: Have you ever actually fixed a compiler error by reading the error message and attempting to understand it? Do you have any understanding at all of the code you've been given? You ought to be able to balance the parentheses yourself at least. As for the operator, if I put "java operators" into Google, the very first result I get is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html , which identifies `||` as logical OR.

Comment: Thanks Finnbarr.. I should have got this..Been struggling with it for around an hour and my brains just shut down. Sorry again, and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that sorts the characters before checking them for equality. This means that compare("string", "gnirts") will return 0. Then use this comparator as you traverse through the list and copy the matching elements to a new list.

Another option (if you have a really large list) is to create an Anagram class that extends the String class. Override the hashcode method so that anagrams produce the same hashcode, then use a hashmap of anagrams to check your array list for anagrams.

Comment: actually, as GreenMatt mentioned above, you can also create a Set<Anagram> and let the Set check for duplicates.

Comment: I guess a good candidate for that hashCode would be: look at the String and its reverse, and take the hashCode of the one that comes first when sorted alphabetically.

Comment: In one of his comments to the original question, OP said he was only interested in only fully reversed strings being considered equal, not arbitrary permutations.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (String str : arraylst)
{
  set.add(str);
}
ArrayList<String> newlst = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String str : arraylst)
{
  if(!set.contains(str))
    newlst.add(str);
}
```

Comment: Won't maintain the list ordering.

Comment: "I would like to remove duplicates from this ArrayList and keep only the first occurence" implies "keep non-duplicated elements in order", I think.

Comment: yurib, when I do as you suggest, I still have the "duplicates" ("string", "gnirts") in the set.

Comment: @Thilo OP said nothing about first occurrences, i don't know who you're quoting.

Comment: He wants to keep `string` (the first occurrence), but discard `gnirts` (the "other"). That is in the question.

Comment: @Thilo again, OP says nothing about keeping any occurrences. read the question without adding your own interpretation.

Comment: People, I think I havent explained my question properly: I have rephrased it now under Edits.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicate items, you can use HashMap (), where as the key codes will be used by the sum of the letters (as each letter has its own code - is not a valid situation where two different words have an identical amount of code numbers), as well as the value - this the word. When adding a new word in a HashMap, if the amount of code letters of new words is identical to some of the existing key in a HashMap, then the word with the same key is replaced by a new word. Thus, we get the HashMap collection of words without repetition.

With regard to the fact that the bottom line "string" looks better "gnirts". It may be a situation where we can not determine which word is better, so the basis has been taken that the final form of the word is not important - thing is that there are no duplicate

```
ArrayList<String> mainList = new ArrayList<String>();

        mainList.add("string,has,was,hctam,gnirts,saw,match,sah");

        String[] listChar = mainList.get(0).split(",");

        HashMap <Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        for (String temp : listChar) {
            int sumStr=0;
            for (int i=0; i<temp.length(); i++)
                sumStr += temp.charAt(i);
            hm.put(sumStr, temp);
        }

        mainList=new ArrayList<String>();

        Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> set = hm.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> temp : set) {
            mainList.add(temp.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println(mainList);
```

**UPD:**
1) The need to maintain txt-file in ANSI

In the beginning, I replaced Scaner on FileReader and BufferedReader

```
String fileRStr = new String();
String stringTemp;

FileReader fileR = new FileReader("text.txt");
BufferedReader streamIn = new BufferedReader(fileR);
while ((stringTemp = streamIn.readLine()) != null)
    fileRStr += stringTemp;
fileR.close();

mainList.add(fileRStr);
```

In addition, all the words in the file must be separated by commas, as the partition ishonoy lines into words by the function split (",").
If you have words separated by another character - replace the comma at the symbol in the following line:

```
String[] listChar = mainList.get(0).split(",");
```

Comment: Hi Torch: I completely understand what you are saying and it makes sense. So one basically obtains the sum of the "strings" and compares them. Got it. However, when I try to implement it, I get strange result: i.e only the first element is compared. the code is on dpaste: http://dpaste.com/677830/ The problem is in line 25 wheere I am able to "get" only the 0th element. How do I speciffy to do it for all elements in the ArrayList? is looping the only option?

Comment: The answer to your question in the comment UPD